# How to load GeoJSON geometric data and drawing grapics in background

Tags: geojson, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I meet a problem when trying to load GeoJSON geometric data and drawing grapics in background.

The main problem is drawing grapics in background, I use graphicLayer and hope each graphic in GeoJSON can 
be drawn on it. I try using web worker to make this processing performed in the background, but it failed.
The main problem is many esri library such as  "esri/Graphic", is a complex object, and inside that has some 
infinite loop function, that cause the web worker can not pass the object to another file, like worker.js.
The code snippet is as following:

```
main.ejs:
 var usingObject = {
  Graphic: Graphic
 }
 const binaryData = msgpack.encode(usingObject);
 const base64String = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, binaryData));
 const worker = new Worker("worker.js");
 worker.postMessage(base64String);
...

worker.js:
 onmessage = function(event) {
    const binaryData = atob(event.dat);
    const uint8Array = new Uint8Array(binaryData.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < binaryData.length; i++) {
    uint8Array[i] = binaryData.charCodeAt(i);
   }
  const usingObject = json.msgpack.decode(uint8Array);
   var graphicsLayer = PlottingOnBackground(usingObject.Graphic);
   postMessage(graphicsLayer);
   };
```

My environment is node.js. Is there any other way to load GeoJSON geometric data and draw graphics in background?